# SQL Order by two fields ASC and DESC

Tags: mysql

I need to order the results of a table according to two fields: `position` and `update_time`. The users are allowed to change the `position` value (by moving the item) and therefore re-order.

However, when the user moves an item I only update the `position` and `update_time` of that item and not of all of the items.

```
table brands
------------------------
id | name         | position | update_time
1    Instagram      2          '2016-06-29 15:41:15'
2    Microsoft      0          '2016-06-30 11:12:13'
3    Twitter        0          '2016-06-30 10:58:57'
4    Stackoverflow  1          '2016-06-30 11:11:52'
5    LinkedIn       0          '2016-06-30 10:41:37'
6    Google         2          '2016-06-30 11:12:40'
```

**My expected result:**

```
id | name         | position | update_time
2    Microsoft      0          '2016-06-30 11:12:13'
4    Stackoverflow  1          '2016-06-30 11:11:52'
6    Google         2          '2016-06-30 11:12:40'
3    Twitter        0          '2016-06-30 10:58:57'
5    LinkedIn       0          '2016-06-30 10:41:37'
1    Instagram      2          '2016-06-29 15:41:15'
```

**The query I'm using:**

```
SELECT *
FROM brands
ORDER BY position ASC, update_time DESC
```

**The result I'm facing:**

```
id | name         | position | update_time
2    Microsoft      0          '2016-06-30 11:12:13'
3    Twitter        0          '2016-06-30 10:58:57'
5    LinkedIn       0          '2016-06-30 10:41:37'
4    Stackoverflow  1          '2016-06-30 11:11:52'
6    Google         2          '2016-06-30 11:12:40'
1    Instagram      2          '2016-06-29 15:41:15'
```

The **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b9f39/2)** that proves the result above.

Is it possible to accomplish what I want through query or do I need to update all the items with the new positions whenever a user moves one item?

Comment: You need to change the position of all the items or use some other method to maintain the ordering.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought so..but well, thank you anyway.

Comment: I fail to see the complexity of this problem.